# High speed (100 MHz) full wave rectifier

Tags: rectifier, high-frequency

I would like to build a full wave rectifier of a RF signal (Vpp should be less than 1V) with a frequency of 10 MHz and carrier at 100 MHz. For example, this could be the signal:

[image]

If possible, the input impedance should be > 1 kΩ. The source can provide up to ~100mA (the final stage of the source is an opamp). I'm afraid I don't know how to exactly characterize this source but if needed, I guess a common-collector BJT could help isolate it.

All the circuits I've seen so far use diodes that, as far as I could tell, don't reach these frequencies (without going to specialized ones). The comments already pointed out that some diodes could reach it, namely the HSMS-28x, MA4E2200x or the 1N5711, my thanks to the commenters!). All solutions are welcomed, even with "specialized diodes". If required, the "gain" could be lower than 1 and go as far as 1/10.

Please bear in mind that I studied electronics a long time ago and never actually worked in this area. (I'm just doing doing this to learn and as a hobby.)

Solutions as this (https://www.electrical4u.com/full-wave-rectifiers/) are, as far as I can tell, dependent on large signals and I'm interested in signals from -0.5V to 0.5V, so using diodes would need to take this into consideration (for example, having a Vt of 0.7V would force the signal to first add a DC in order to operate from 0,7V to 1,7V)

Another solution would be :
[image]

from here (https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/half-wave-and-full-wave-precision-rectifier-circuit-using-op-amp) but I believe this doesn't reach the 100 MHz.

Comment: What is the nature of the source and load, how do they need to be connected? What purpose is this for?

Comment: It's unclear what your actual _question_ is. It sounds like you want a complete design.

Comment: @pipe yes, ideally I would like a complete design.

Comment: @TimWilliams maybe I'm wrong, but by specifying that the Zi should be at least 1kohm I already specified the source. The load should also be more than 1kohm. Thank you.

Comment: an RF signal with a frequency of 10 MHz and a carrier at 100 MHz: you mean a 110 MHz tone?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @mabeco and by specifying the input impedance of the rectifier, you did *not* specify the source impedance. Please do. Also, it's really not clear what you want the output to be – a faithful representation of the rectified signal (why?? You'd do that with a baseband or IF version), or some kind of power-harvesting step? Or is this about power measurement? In each case, your design would look different. The thing here is: *asking for a full design* is already **too broad** (and your question might get closed for that), but not fully describing the purpose and requirements of your circuit …

Comment: … definitely puts the question over the edge of "needs more detail AND more focus, don't invest time into answering" for many of us. You mention that you don't want to use specialized diodes – why? What can you then use? When we propose a solution, will you just come around with another surprising restriction? Too many red flags in one question.)

Comment: There are detector diodes that can reach these frequencies (HSMS-28x, MA4E2200x).

Comment: Oh come on, this question has a simple answer, and is not too broad. The assumption that diodes are too slow is wrong. And that's that. Case in point: use 1N5711. It was designed for that job. Input impedance is no big deal - you can always add a buffer stage, and BJTs are great for that. Or just use one of the many ICs that have heterodyne RF front-ends.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica fair enough. Can you convert that to an answer, then?

Comment: @winny I believe now the question has some circuits

Comment: @MarcusMüller I added an example of the signal to rectify and I hope to have addressed all of your questions. If not, please say so.

Comment: @LiorBilia thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: This edit only raises further questions: what op-amp is the signal from? (Op-amps capable of such frequencies are not trivial beasts.) Is the signal single-ended or differential? Is it impedance matched or raw? Is it on a board (in which case how shall it be connected e.g. BNC or etc.), or part of a design in progress so the connectivity is an open matter?  Why specify "full wave", is there a particular reason you desire this? Would half-wave suffice? How linear must it be? Are you just doing an envelope (AM) detector?

Comment: Also, your signal shows BPSK, if I'm not mistaken. Is an amplitude detector really what is needed here?

Comment: If you are buffering it, you clearly aren’t after extracting RF energy. What’s your end goal for the full wave rectified signal.